# What is this kind of sorting called and how do I properly implement it in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I am working on re-implementing one of my WordPress plugins in React (Gutenberg). One of the features is re-sorting a list of input fields via a draggable UI element, this was easily implemented without React as I could move the DOM nodes around.

Now, I am rewriting everything in React and things have been going well so far. However, now I am hung up on how to shift the elements around in a sorted list by mutating its data.

Here is a mockup of what I have so far: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-et2r6u?file=src/data.js

What I want is clicking the up arrow changes the `sort` value of the selected object, then the other items in array also adjust their `sort` value according, so the array items all have a `sort` key that is in ascending order.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Sorting should be easy with javascript's `.sort()` function. Or you can use a react drag and drop library like https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about if it's about drag and drop and not sorting.

Comment: This more than using `Array.sort()` plus I am trying to avoid DND for a couple of reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always preferred to provide just the relevant **[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** lines-of-code within the question.

Thanks, though, for the [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-et2r6u?file=src/data.js), which was helpful.

The issue was that the `setInstructions` method needs to be invoked with the properly updated `instructions` array.

The below code helps achieve that:

```
export default function InstructionLine({
  index,
  instruction,
  instructions,
  setInstructions,
}) {
  function sortList(elt, direction = 'up') {
    const { sort } = elt;
    const newIns = [...instructions];
    if (direction === 'up') {
        newIns[sort] = { ...instructions[+sort - 1], sort: +sort };
        newIns[+sort - 1] = { ...instructions[sort], sort: +sort - 1 };
    } else {
        newIns[sort] = { ...instructions[+sort + 1], sort: +sort };
        newIns[+sort + 1] = { ...instructions[sort], sort: +sort + 1 };
    }
    console.log(newIns);
    setInstructions(newIns);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <li>
        <div>
          {instruction.sort > 0 && (<span className="up" onClick={() => sortList(instruction)}>
            <>&#x022D6;</>
          </span>)}
          {instruction.sort < instructions.length - 1 && (<span className="down" onClick={() => sortList(instruction, 'down')}>
            <>&#x022D7;</>
          </span>)}
        </div>
        {instruction.description || <h2>{instruction.grouptitle}</h2>}
      </li>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Explanation of changes**

- Instead of two methods `sortUp` and `sortDown` one common method with a `direction` parameter is used
- Using the `sort` prop as the `index` to the array, the two elements (which need to be interchanged) are identified and their `sort` prop updated
- The `setInstructions` method is invoked using the updated array `newIns`

**EDIT**

- The solution has been updated to conditionally render the `up`, `down` buttons (in the `<span>` elements).
- Thus the top item no longer has an `up` button & the bottom/last item no longer has a `down` button.

Comment: Sir, thank you so much for this!
What would you call this type of sorting, for future reference? Also, I noticed a bug in your implementation where if you sort an item to the end of the list, it will keep going.

Comment: @jsNoob 
I think I have fixed that bug by checking if we are at the top of the list and return'ing early

Comment: _What would you call this type of sorting_ <-- I am still a learner/student of JavaScript. I'd leave it to the experts in Stackoverflow to categorize this - in fact, I don't know if there's any special **type of sorting** for this. To me, it looks like a simple Vanilla JS `sort`.